# Get last launch date of the application

Tags: android

I'm writing android launcher, and my current problem is how to get last app lauch time.

I can wriite my own method to save launch time in database, but this will work only after user will launch apps, any ideas to get that time with public android api?

Comment: I don't think Android keeps this kind of information so doing it yourself would be the only way.

Comment: Well, thanks. Will write my own method, but if someone knows public api method would be great;